# 5V 1A vs 5V 5A power supply for 6 LED + Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, power

If I want to power up 6 normal 3mm LED with the appropriate series limiting resistor, do I need the 5V with **1A** or **5A** power supply? Same goes to the Arduino, if I want to power it externally, do I go for the **1A** or **5A**?

Comment: Both will work, but using a 5A one is quite a bit of overkill.

Comment: If I'm using 5A, will be voltage drop of the resistor be more or less? Should it be more since it needs to resist more current, hence more voltage drop

Comment: @Jason "series limiting resistor" will limit the current.

Comment: The 5A refers to the maximum current it can supply. If you draw less, it will supply less. As long as the voltage is the same, there will be the same amount of current flowing through the led.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your led, it will draw 10 to 20mA for a standard led. Thats 0.010 to 0.020A. Multiply this by 6 and you see that a 1A power supply will be enough.

Your arduino, when driving those leds, will also use a few mA. So you can power everything with a 1A power supply.

Answer (score 0):

Both will work, but **go with 1A!!!**

It is more forgiving if a short happens.

A 5A short circuit will make sparks that might be dangerous.